# Issue when documenting new "+" S3 method with roxygen2

Tags: r, roxygen2

I am trying to define a new "+" S3 method in my package for a class `class1`. I use `roxygen2` to generate the function man page, and I encounter an issue when documenting the usage of the function, the issue being either a strange "Usage" section in the man page, or warnings when checking the package.

This "+" S3 method can take one or two operands like the standard addition:

```
#' Add objects of type "class1"
#' @rdname add.class1
#' 
#' @param x an object of class "class1"
#' @param y an object of class "class1"
#'
#' @return an object of class "class1"
#' @export
"+.class1" <- function(x, y = NULL) {
    if(!is.null(y)) {
        return(class1(x$value + y$value))
    } else {
        return(class1(+ x$value))
    }
}
```

If I don't specify any `@usage` section in the `roxygen2` documentation chunk, when I generate the man page (with `devtools::document()`) and read the function doc (with `?"+.class1"`), I get the following in the "Usage" section of the man page (which is not very clear in my opinion):

```
## S3 method for class 'class1'
x + y = NULL
```

If I specify a `@usage` section in the `roxygen2` documentation chunk of the `+.class1` method, like this:

```
#' Add objects of type "class1"
#' @rdname add.class1
#' @usage
#' +x
#' x + y
#'
#' @param x an object of class "class1"
#' @param y an object of class "class1"
#'
#' @return an object of class "class1"
#' @export
"+.class1" <- function(x, y = NULL) {
    if(!is.null(y)) {
        return(class1(x$value + y$value))
    } else {
        return(class1(+ x$value))
    }
}
```

I get a pretty "Usage" section in the man page:

```
+x
x + y
```

But I get a warning when checking the package:

```
Objects in \usage without \alias in documentation object '+.class1':
  ‘+’
```

I can add an alias in the `roxygen2` documentation chunk with `@aliases +` like this:

```
#' Add objects of type "class1"
#' @rdname add.class1
#' @aliases +
#' @usage
#' +x
#' x + y
#'
#' @param x an object of class "class1"
#' @param y an object of class "class1"
#'
#' @return an object of class "class1"
#' @export
"+.class1" <- function(x, y = NULL) {
    if(!is.null(y)) {
        return(class1(x$value + y$value))
    } else {
        return(class1(+ x$value))
    }
}
```

then the warning is gone, but in practice I am implementing two classes with their own "+" S3 method, then if I have a `@usage` tag (to get nice man page "Usage" section) and a `@aliases +` tag (to avoid the warning I just mentioned above) in both class `roxygen` documentation chunks (c.f. below), I get a new warning:

```
Rd files with duplicated alias '+':
  ‘add.class1.Rd’ ‘add.class2.Rd’
```

Definition of `class1` and `class2` "+" S3 methods:

```
#' Add objects of type "class1"
#' @rdname add.class1
#' @aliases +
#' @usage
#' +x
#' x + y
#'
#' @param x an object of class "class1"
#' @param y an object of class "class1"
#'
#' @return an object of class "class1"
#' @export
"+.class1" <- function(x, y = NULL) {
    if(!is.null(y)) {
        return(class1(x$value + y$value))
    } else {
        return(class1(+ x$value))
    }
}

#' Add objects of type "class2"
#' @rdname add.class2
#' @aliases +
#' @usage
#' +x
#' x + y
#'
#' @param x an object of class "class2"
#' @param y an object of class "class2"
#'
#' @return an object of class "class2"
#' @export
"+.class2" <- function(x, y = NULL) {
    if(!is.null(y)) {
        return(class2(x$value + y$value))
    } else {
        return(class2(+ x$value))
    }
}
```

**Edit:** solution thanks to @user2554330 suggestion:

```
#' @usage
#' \special{+x}
#' \special{x + y}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax used in the help page for `+.Date` is

```
\special{date + x}
```

(see https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/d99a0b4cfe4435b212f0eb689ba0b853310c9695/src/library/base/man/Ops.Date.Rd#L19)

As far as I can see, the `\special{}` macro is almost completely undocumented, so you might get some sort of warning for using it.

The `bit64` package uses different syntax:

```
\method{+}{integer64}(e1,e2)
```

which is displayed as

```
## S3 method for class 'integer64'
e1 + e2
```

(see https://github.com/truecluster/bit64/blob/e428535bc31982d85bc3f4faa1f2ae8481280781/man/xor.integer64.rd#L35)

Similarly, the `bit` package documents unary `!` with

```
\method{!}{bit}(x)
```

and it is displayed as `!x`.  This style seems like a better choice than using `\special{}`.

Edited to add:  I tried `\method{+}{bit}(x)` and it failed, presumably because `+` is a binary operator, even though it can be used in a unary way.  So maybe you should just skip the unary usage, or use the `\special{}` macro to document it.

Comment: Thanks! It works when using the `\special{}` macro inside the `@usage` roxygen2 tag.